# Mongodb query not returning record, even data present in array

Tags: mongodb

I am searching term in an array of String, even I get the result for the record which contains only the search term in the array, but the mongo query does not return the other record which contain search term along with other values.

I tried elemMatch() operator with find() and aggregate() query but it fails to return the record. I want contain like query. If array contain search term return that record.

`db.getCollection('testData').find({"acronyms": "JNTU"})`

Here 'acronyms' is an array of String.

I want records which contains 'JNTU' term in it's array.
e.g Assume below is the collection

```
record1: ["JNTU", "JNTUK"]
record2:["JNTU"]
record3:[]
```

I expect:
record1: ["JNTU", "JNTUK"]
record2:["JNTU"]
as output

Comment: can you share your schema, sample collection.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB has a `$regex` operator which allows a regular expression to be submitted as a query.

```js
db.getCollection('testData').find({"acronyms":  { "$regex": "JNTU", "$options": "i" }})
```

Now this will contain all the result documents which contain the string `JNTU` as a part of the data.

To know more you can read this awesome documentation
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/

Comment: I want record with an exact match.

Comment: It is not working for me. I could not figure out the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query.

db.getCollection('testData').find({
    "acronyms":  /JNTU/
});

Comment: Yes you are right but it will do a partial match, hence you will get the both the records.

Comment: No, because it does partial match. I want query which checks array contains the search term.